# Rest Assured Automation

Tags: java, rest-assured

How to post request JSON Data and attach file to upload
actually there is a form which contains attachment so how to send request to fill form and attach image file

```
Response response = given().config(config).header(key, value).header(contentType, "multipart/mixed")
                .multiPart("attachment[]", upleadFile).body(jsonBody).when().post(apiURL).then().statusCode(200).extract().response();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution use this.
In first we are passing exact key like attachment[]
and for other objects

```
{

    Response response = 
                given().header(key, value).
                multiPart("attachment[]", new File("E:/Lightshot/Screenshot_2.png")).
                multiPart("issueTypeId", json.get("issueTypeId").toString()).
                multiPart("relationJson",json.get("relationJson").toString()).
                multiPart("url",json.get("url").toString())
                .when().post(apiURL).then().statusCode(200).extract().response();
        return response;
}
```